# Finding an exact match for a dataset in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a lot of numeric data in one column that I have pieced together from various other worksheets.

I found some data in another worksheet that may be a copy of data I already inserted into the column but I am not sure if its already inserted or not.

Is there a way of comparing the mystery data I have in one column to the collected results in another column and return true if an exact match of the data is found?

By exact match I mean in its content and the order the content is displayed in.

Comment: The logical solution would be VBA. Look for the first line of the mystery data in your big list. If you find it, compare the two next lines. If those match, continue line by line until you've tested the whole mystery list. If it doesn't match at any point, go back and start the comparison at the next line of the big list.  Repeat until you either find a match or exhaust the big list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I love this question and it has a nice answer (I think). The trick is to check in your "pieced together dataset" (I'll call it 'WholeSet') if it matches the other set (I'll call it 'SourceSet') piece by piece.

There are two assumptions that I need to make:

- SourceSet is in the same order as its matching data in WholeSet
- SourceSet is not at the very beginnen of WholeSet (you can check that manually very easy).

In the sheet (see pic below), I have `0` in B2 and in B3, I have `=IF(A3=OFFSET($D$2;B2;0);B2+1;0)`. Next, I copied B3 down to the end. In G1 is the formula: `=MATCH(COUNT(D:D);B:B;0)-COUNT(D:D)+1`.

[image]

Explanation of the B-column formula: search the next record (using the offset function) and if it's not found, enter 0 (so next, we'll look for the first record, with 0 offset).

Explanation of the G1 formula: search for the number of items in SourceSet. If found, `MATCH` returns the row number of the last item. Subtract the number of items in SourceSet to get to the first item and then add one, because WholeSet starts at row 2.

Comment: Simple, elegant and perfect for an Excel noob like me. Thanks!

Comment: Your approach only works if the first occurrence of a matching first number is the start of the matching list.  Change A5 to 1.  That shouldn't affect the fact that the sourceset matches starting in A6, but it fails because starting the comparison in A5 doesn't match.